# How can use Facebook Requests On Adobe Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I used Facebook requests in Web application like this.

```
Facebook.ui( "apprequests", {message:"blrablrablra"}, CallBackFuction, null );
```

But in air, Mobile doesn't have `ui`; only have `api` so I don't know what I have to do.

How can I make Facebook Requests using `FacebookMobile.api`?

Anyway is that possible?

Comment: finally i finded solution !! that is using ane its only way to send request is using native